# RouteXL: sample code, how it works?

Tags: javascript, routes

I read API documentation and I test the sample code of Github in Javascript.
When iread the result of tour method of the outeXL_API_Connector() object. It retuns a object. I tryed to parse to json but it doesn't anybody knows how to work with it?.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The object has the contents as described in the [API documentation](https://www.routexl.nl/blog/api/#post-tour). Here is a screenshot when debugging:

[image]